Loading Germany map to ors app on docker - decoding .tiff error
I am fairly new to QGIS and docker so I would like to ask more experienced people. I am calculating driving time isochrones for over 60min reach in QGIS.
To do so I installed ORS app in container in docker and downloaded German map from Geofabrik.de (in .pbf).
Unfortunately when I try to load map into container it answers me with ERROR (last 4 verses of below logs). It is happening only with whole Germany's map and the part of Germany map for Mecklenburg-Vorpommern region. Rest of the countries like Poland, Czechia, Slovakia, other part of Germany work just fine (even combined together in osmosis app). The problem is with some srtm_41_01.tif that cant be decoded. From this point I have no clue what to do next. Previous maps of Germany (from 2023, 2022) have same error.
Below I attach all logs from start of app to error when it cancels loading map.
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.Application                      ]   Starting Application v8.0.0 using Java 21.0.2 with PID 1 (/ors.jar started by root in /home/ors)
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.Application                      ]   The following 1 profile is active: "default"
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.ORSEnvironmentPostProcessor      ]
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.ORSEnvironmentPostProcessor      ]   Configuration lookup started.
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.ORSEnvironmentPostProcessor      ]   Configuration file set by environment variable.
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.ORSEnvironmentPostProcessor      ]   Loaded file '/home/ors/config/ors-config.yml'
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.ORSEnvironmentPostProcessor      ]   Configuration lookup finished.
2024-04-18 09:01:52 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.ORSEnvironmentPostProcessor      ]
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                              ORS-Init [ o.h.o.a.s.l.ORSInitContextListener       ]   Initializing ORS...
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                              ORS-Init [ o.h.o.r.RoutingProfileManager            ]   Total - 1024 MB, Free - 964.91 MB, Max: 11 GB, Used - 59.09 MB
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                              ORS-Init [ o.h.o.r.RoutingProfileManager            ]   ====> Initializing profiles from '/home/ors/files/de.osm.pbf' (1 threads) ...
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                              ORS-Init [ o.h.o.r.RoutingProfileManager            ]   1 profile configurations submitted as tasks.
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                            ORS-pl-car [ o.h.o.r.RoutingProfile                   ]   [1] Profiles: 'driving-car', location: '/home/ors/./graphs/car'.
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                            ORS-pl-car [ o.h.o.r.g.e.c.CoreLMPreparationHandler   ]   Loaded landmark splitting collection from
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                            ORS-pl-car [ o.h.o.r.g.e.ORSGraphHopper               ]   version v4.9.1|2024-01-17T09:08:46Z (7,20,5,4,5,7)
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                            ORS-pl-car [ o.h.o.r.g.e.ORSGraphHopper               ]   graph CH|car_ors|RAM_STORE|3D|turn_cost|,,,,, details:edges:0(0MB), nodes:0(0MB), name:(0MB), geo:0(0MB), bounds:1.7976931348623157E308,-1.7976931348623157E308,1.7976931348623157E308,-1.7976931348623157E308,1.7976931348623157E308,-1.7976931348623157E308, shortcuts:0 (0MB), nodesCH:-1 (0MB), shortcuts:0 (0MB), nodesCH:-1 (0MB), shortcuts:0 (0MB), nodesCH:-1 (0MB)
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                            ORS-pl-car [ o.h.o.r.g.e.ORSGraphHopper               ]   No custom areas are used, custom_areas.directory not given
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                            ORS-pl-car [ o.h.o.r.g.e.ORSGraphHopper               ]   start creating graph from /home/ors/files/de.osm.pbf
2024-04-18 09:01:55 INFO                                            ORS-pl-car [ o.h.o.r.g.e.ORSGraphHopper               ]   using CH|car_ors|RAM_STORE|3D|turn_cost|,,,,, memory:totalMB:1024, usedMB:267
2024-04-18 09:01:56 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.Application                      ]   Started Application in 4.501 seconds (process running for 6.122)
2024-04-18 09:01:56 INFO                                                  main [ o.h.o.a.Application                      ]   openrouteservice {"build_date":"2024-03-21T13:55:54Z","version":"8.0.0"}
2024-04-18 09:04:36 WARN                                            ORS-pl-car [ c.g.r.d.CGIARProvider                    ]   cannot load srtm_41_01, error: Not a GraphHopper file /home/ors/elevation_cache/srtm_41_01.gh! Expected 'GH' as file marker but was
2024-04-18 09:04:37 ERROR                                             ORS-Init [ o.h.o.r.RoutingProfileManager            ]
2024-04-18 09:04:37 ERROR                                             ORS-Init [ o.h.o.r.RoutingProfileManager            ]   Failed to either read or execute the ors configuration and its parameters: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't process file /home/ors/files/de.osm.pbf, error: Can't decode srtm_41_01.tif
2024-04-18 09:04:37 ERROR                                             ORS-Init [ o.h.o.r.RoutingProfileManager            ]

Sounds like files are in wrong directories. It tried to load a elevation tif as graphhopper file I think?

Is it possible to make it load differently? Make it work? I have no clue how this files are connected to each other.
